# Why is worksheet copy omitting cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro spreadsheet to cleanse a lot of data.  The cells start at D1 with columns A - C showing ActiveX buttons to process the cleansing VBA tasks.  The last button is to save the cells with values to a new workbook and prompt user to select name and destination.  This is an image of what the worksheet being copied looks like concerning where data starts and buttons.

[image]

The code below creates the workbook and prompts user but ONLY copies first row (the headers) and cells with actual values are omitted.  Why is this happening?

```
Private Sub saveSheet_Click()

Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim bFileSaveAs As Boolean

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
Workbooks("Cleansing Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets("Cleaning Records").Range("D1:AX" & Lastrow).Copy
NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AU" & Lastrow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

bFileSaveAs = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
If Not bFileSaveAs Then MsgBox "User cancelled", vbCritical

End Sub
```

Comment: Column `A` in `Cleaning Records` is empty or has a value only in cell `A1`? If so, for the `LastRow`, maybe use `4` instead of `1`, or `"D"` to make it more readable.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I have edited to add image of worksheet

Comment: The image makes it rather obvious, doesn't it?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Ah!  Thanks I have it solved.  I changed what you suggested and made Lastrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: You know that `Range("D" & Rows.Count)` and `Cells(Rows.Count, "D")` and `Cells(Rows.Count, 4)` all do the same thing? If you didn't know, now you do.

Comment: @VBasic2008 LOL thanks again.  First time I have actually used buttons directly on the excel form.  Understand now why it was throwing off the original Lastrow code line